# Using Moq to mock an interface that extends IList

Tags: c#, moq

I am attempting to mock an interface that extends IList and get the mock to work as an IEnumerable. I was expecting the mocked object to contain an enumerable list of users, instead the enumeration yields no results. The code below works if I change the interface ITestEnumerable extends to IEnumerable instead of IList.

```
public interface ITestEnumerable : IList<User>
{

}

[Fact]
public void TestTest()
{
    //Arrange
    var fakes = new List<User>()
    {
        new User() { DisplayName = "Joe Smith", Mail = "jsmith@test.com" },
        new User() { DisplayName = "Jane Doe", Mail = "jdoe@test.com" }
    };
    var mockTest = new Mock<ITestEnumerable>();
    mockTest.Setup(t => t.Count).Returns(() => fakes.Count());
    mockTest.Setup(t => t[It.IsAny<int>()]).Returns<int>(i => fakes.ElementAt(i));
    mockTest.As<IEnumerable<User>>().Setup(t => t.GetEnumerator()).Returns(() => fakes.GetEnumerator());
    var testList = new List<User>();

    //Act
    testList.AddRange(mockTest.Object);

    //Assert
    Assert.NotNull(testList[0]);
}
```

Comment: `AddRange` will attempt to cast the `IEnumerable<T>` to a `ICollection<T>` and use `CopyTo` instead of iterating the `IEnumerable`  https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,79de3e39e69a4811,references

Comment: What exactly does your interface add to `IList`.  Have you considered using composition instead of inheritance?  It's usually best not to extend existing collections and your interface looks like it would be implemented by something that inherits from `List<User>`.

Comment: I'm trying to mock IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage which is part of Microsoft's graph service library. It Implements IList. The method under test uses this library to talk to Office 365, which I don't want to happen during testing. The code above was just a simplification to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Instead of mocking you might want to just use an implementation, either a real one or just a fake one for testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is in the internals of AddRange function: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,79de3e39e69a4811

You can see, that first attempt is to cast it to ICollection and then there is a whole CopyTo flow.

So the easiest would be to replace it with something like this. You do mock enumerator anyway. It can also be shortened with LINQ.

```
foreach(var item in mockTest.Object)
{
    testList.Add(item);
}
```

If you want to do this with MOQ, something like this should fit:

```
mockTest.As<ICollection<User>>().Setup(t => t.CopyTo(It.IsAny<User[]>(), It.IsAny<int>())).Callback<User[], int>((u,c) => fakes.CopyTo(u,c));
```